# Dynamic Javascript in a Leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, leaflet

```
 $.ajax({
      url: // asp.net project site with relevant info,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "HTML",
      cache: false
 }).done(function (data) {
       popup.setContent(data);
       marker.bindPopup(popup);
 }).fail(function (data) {
        throw "createPopup(): AJAX call failed!";
 })
```

And my view that gets called:

```
model TodayIT.TrackOnline.Maps.Models.Balance

<div id="container" class="containers" style="height: 300px; width: 400px;">This page loaded succesfully!</div>

<script>
    alert("hi");
</script>
```

Nothing happens when the popup loads the page succesfully: the popup displays the text in the #container div, but does not perform the alert. What's going on?

Comment: Dropping content via `.innerHTML` will not run embedded `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the alternative?

Comment: Well when you use the jQuery `.html()` API, the library explicitly looks for `<script>` tags and it arranges for them to be run. It looks like you're using something else to drop the loaded content.